# how to encode dynamic django variable from a html template in python coding

Tags: python, django

I would like to encode '{{ variable }}' and '{% for loop ...%}' from a template to a variable called 'html'. So that I can render it as PDF file using pisa.CreatePDF. I am using xhtml2pdf to generate PDF.

```
html="<html><body>{% for inventory in filter.qs %} {{ inventory.pk }} {{ inventory.name }} {{ inventory.price }} {{ inventory.quantity }} {% endfor %} </body></html>".
```

the code above is not working.

it doesn't give any values from database. Simply the text below:
    {% for inventory in filter.qs %} {{ inventory.pk }} {{ inventory.name }} {% endfor %} in the PDF output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

html = """
<html>
<body>
  {% for inventory in inventories %} 
    {{ inventory.pk }} {{ inventory.name }} {{ inventory.price }} {{ inventory.quantity }} 
  {% endfor %} 
</body>
</html>
"""
t = Template(html)
inventories  = Inventory.objects.all()
c = Context({'filter': filter})
raw_html = t.render(c)
print(raw_html)
```

See more at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: I am unclear on how to assign the quaryset for 'filter'. I've tried to run  "filter = filter.qs" but not working. the filter is getting information from filter.py where the code as such: inventory = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains'). thanks for reply

Comment: I don't know how does django_filter work, so I edited my post without using it. If you do want to use it, read its documentation please.

Comment: Thanks. your method help me solve one part of the problem. Thanks a lot.